# C++ Simple file reading

Tags: c++

I have a file,named f1.txt, whose contents are
75 15 85 35 60 50 45 70

Here is my code to read each integer and print them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  fstream file("f1.txt", ios::in);
  int i;
  while(!file.eof()) {
    file >> i;
    cout << i << " ";
 }

return 0;
}
```

But when I compiled and run the program, the output is 
75 15 85 35 60 50 45 70 70.
Why it is reading the last integer twice ? Any clues ?

Comment: This question has been asked one way or another many times on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
while(file >> i)
    cout << i << " ";
```

Answer (score 4):

std::stream doesn't set eof() until a read fails, so one fix is:

```
while (file >> i, !file.eof()) cout << i << " ";
```

Comment: the `, !file.eof()` is unnecessary since `file >> i` will return a reference to `file` which when converting to a bool will yield the current stream fail state.

Comment: Sure: it's a little more unclear, but I don't mind either way.